# Stopping swing Timer after it have executed one time

Tags: java, swing, timer, repeat

In a game that I'm making I have a power up that I only want to be visible for 10 seconds and then disapear. Therefor whenever you get the power up I run a swing `Timer` that have it's initial delay set to 10 seconds (10_000) and I have also set repeats to false so it should only run one time.

Whenever I first get the power up it will only be visible for 10 seconds as intended but when I get it again it will only be visible for a random amount of time (but never over 10 seconds) so therefor it seems like it does repeat itself. So how can I make it stop after it have runne one time when `setRepeats(false);` doesn't work?

This is the code for what happens when you get the power up.

```
if(!power.getPowerUp()){
 double xAirdrop = xSize - 500;
 double yAirdrop = ySize - 500;
 power.setX(Math.random() * xAirdrop + 64);
 power.setY(Math.random() * yAirdrop + 150);
 power.setPowerUp(true);
 Timer powerTimer = new Timer(10_000, new ActionListener(){
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
   power.setPowerUp(false);  
   power.setWidth(power.getCrate().getWidth(null) + 250);
   power.setHeight(power.getCrate().getHeight(null) + 250);
  }
 });
 powerTimer.setInitialDelay(10_000);
 powerTimer.setRepeats(false);
 powerTimer.start();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your timer is still running even though it is not firing events, therefore when you run `start()` it is somewhere in the middle of the cycle.  This causes for it to run for a shorter time than 10 seconds.  You need to run `restart()` instead of `start()` on subsequent runs.  It might even work for the first run.

```
 powerTimer.setInitialDelay(10_000);
 powerTimer.setRepeats(false);
 powerTimer.restart();
```

From the javadoc:

> restart() 
>             Restarts the Timer, canceling any pending firings and causing it to fire with its initial delay.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html#restart()